Agda: prove that ¬Any≃All¬, FromTo base case
following the PLFA I'm trying to prove that
¬Any≃All¬ : ∀ {A : Set} → {P : A → Set} → (xs : List A) → (¬_ ∘ Any P) xs ≃ All (¬_ ∘ P) xs

My problem is with
FromTo : ∀ {A : Set} → {P : A → Set} → (xs : List A) → (v : (¬_ ∘ Any P) xs) → ((from xs) ∘ (to xs)) v ≡ v 

If xs ≡ [], then I am not sure if ¬ Any P [] is unhabited or not.  I think it is unhabited, but when I try
FromTo [] () 

I get an error:
(¬_ ∘ Any P) [] should be empty, but that's not obvious to me
when checking the clause left hand side
FromTo [] ()


There is only one lambda from the empty type to the empty type, the empty lambda. We can use extensionality to prove the two lambdas are equal. And since there is no element in the empty type, the lambda inside the extensionality is the empty lambda.
FromTo [] t = extensionality (λ {()})


The error message tells you that it's not obvious to Agda that what you claim to be empty actually is. And indeed Any P [] is empty (if you look at the constructors for Any, their return types all mention a non-empty list) and so its negation (¬_ ∘ Any P) [] (aka ¬ (Any P [])) is trivially provable by \ ().

I think the problem may be in this line:
FromTo : ∀ {A : Set} → {P : A → Set} → (xs : List A) → (v : (¬_ ∘ Any P) xs) → ((from xs) ∘ (to xs)) v ≡ v

I would expect to see from (to v) ≡ v, not what you wrote.

The definition of the "from" you wrote is "from xs", and the second from is the one Im actually working with.
